# How to auto derive FromJSON using Template Haskell, Aeson, and type families

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, aeson, type-families

I would like to use template haskell to auto generate the ToJSON (Bar Baz), or FromJSON (Bar Baz) instances. the deriveJSON is of type `Options -> Name -> Q [Dec]` how to I construct the `Name` type when the type takes parameters?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.TH

data Baz = Baz String

class Foo a where
  data Bar a :: *


instance Foo Baz where
  data Bar Baz = ExampleRecord { exampleField1 :: String
                               , exampleField2 :: String
                               }
data Biz = Biz String

instance Foo Biz where
  data Bar Biz = ExampleBizRecord1 { biz1 :: String } 
               | ExampleBizRecord2 { biz2 :: String }

type BarBaz = Bar Baz

-- doesn't work
deriveJSON defaultOptions (''Bar ''Baz)
deriveJSON defaultOptions mkName "Bar Baz"

-- Creates the Name but not supported by Data.Aeson.TH
derive JSON defaultOptions ''BarBaz
```

How to use the deriveJSON when Foo takes a type as a parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try the "obvious" thing it won't work, but the TH error gives a helpful hint:

```
Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
  Data.Aeson.TH.withType: Cannot use a data family name. Use a data family instance constructor instead.
Code: deriveJSON defaultOptions ''Bar
```

Doing what is suggests seems to work:

```
deriveJSON defaultOptions 'ExampleRecord
```

gets you an `instance {From/To}JSON (Bar Baz)`.

---

The same thing works for the update example. Just use *any one* constructor name:

```
data Biz = Biz String

instance Foo Biz where
  data Bar Biz = ExampleBizRecord1 { biz1 :: String } 
               | ExampleBizRecord2 { biz2 :: String }

deriveJSON defaultOptions 'ExampleBizRecord1 
-- XOR 
deriveJSON defaultOptions 'ExampleBizRecord2
```

Comment: Ok so if the data type looked like this `data Bar Baz = ExampleRecord1 String | ExampleRecord2` then that is not possible right? because then you would get duplicate instances.

Comment: Well that isn't a valid data type declaration. You could have `data Bar a = ..` however. How you use the TH function will indeed depend on whether the datatype is a data family or not.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand. I edited my question to show that I would also like to auto generate instances for `Bar Biz`. Or is that not even possible?

Comment: See my edit. The new example doesn't differ from the old one in any way relevant to the topic at hand.